# How to find longest consecutive result set?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT team1, score1, score2, team2, gameDate 
FROM GAMES 
WHERE team1 = 'Tottenham Hotspur' 
   OR team2 = 'Tottenham Hotspur'
ORDER BY gameDate ASC;
```

This query returns game result and game date (for 'Tottenham Hotspur') sorted by game date.

```
team1                score1  score2   team2                     gameDate 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Tottenham Hotspur      0     0        Manchester City           2010-08-14
Stoke City             1     2        Tottenham Hotspur         2010-08-21
Tottenham Hotspur      0     1        Wigan Athletic            2010-08-28
West Bromwich Albion   1     1        Tottenham Hotspur         2010-09-11
Tottenham Hotspur      3     1        Wolverhampton Wanderers   2010-09-18
West Ham United        1     0        Tottenham Hotspur         2010-09-25
Tottenham Hotspur      2     1        Aston Villa               2010-10-02
Fulham                 1     2        Tottenham Hotspur         2010-10-16
Tottenham Hotspur      1     1        Everton                   2010-10-23
Manchester United      2     0        Tottenham Hotspur         2010-10-30
Bolton Wanderers       4     2        Tottenham Hotspur         2010-11-06
Tottenham Hotspur      1     1        Sunderland                2010-11-09
```

How to find here longest consecutive win/lose result set?

In above example, max 4 consecutive game play (sorted by game date) doesn't have draw result and we want to filter those games

```
team1                score1  score2   team2                     gameDate 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Tottenham Hotspur      3     1        Wolverhampton Wanderers   2010-09-18
West Ham United        1     0        Tottenham Hotspur         2010-09-25
Tottenham Hotspur      2     1        Aston Villa               2010-10-02
Fulham                 1     2        Tottenham Hotspur         2010-10-16
```

Comment: What if there is multiple piece longest nondraw games?  (4 non draw game, then draw and then again 4 non draw game). What result do you want in this case?

Comment: Just one piece then. better would be last one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tttt.* from (
    SELECT ttt.*, RANK() over(order by res desc, seqcnt desc , grp desc) rnk from (
        SELECT tt.*, count(*) over( partition by grp, res) as seqcnt from (
             SELECT t.*,  ROW_NUMBER() over(order by gameDate) - ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by res order by gameDate) as  grp from (
                SELECT  team1, score1, score2, team2, gameDate, case when score1= score2 then  'D' else 'N' end as res 
                FROM GAMES  WHERE team1 = 'Tottenham Hotspur' OR team2 = 'Tottenham Hotspur'
            ) t
        ) tt
    ) ttt 
) tttt WHERE rnk = 1 order by gameDate
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
SELECT team1, score1, score2, team2, gameDate 
FROM GAMES 
WHERE team1 = 'Tottenham Hotspur' 
   OR team2 = 'Tottenham Hotspur' 
and score1<>score2 
ORDER BY gameDate ASC
```